# Sound/brightness controls not working after fresh OS intall, WIFI partially working

Tags: wireless, nvidia, sound, dell, brightness

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my computer and I have noticed a few issues:

1. I can't play any sound on the computer's native speakers, however, when I connect a Bluetooth device like headphones, the sound works for the device.
2. The screen's brightness controller (on the top-right menu) doesn't have any effect on the screen's brightness
3. I can only see 2.4GHz Wifi networks.

Now, from what I read on various forums, it seems these issues are linked.
I have tried all the steps described [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) but it didn't work.

The output of `inxi -ANGz` is as follows:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics 
  driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] driver: nvidia v: 440.100 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 640M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.100 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-45-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet driver: alx 
  Device-3: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb
```

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: In case that helps, I have a DELL XPS One 2710. Please help, I don't know what to do!

Comment: For the brightness issue, I've tried updating the linux kernel as I read on several posts that it could fix the issue. But I was unsuccessful as the kernels are unsigned and secureboot doesn't let them boot because of that. I tried deactivating secureboot but the brightness control is still not working it seems.

Comment: I also tried all the steps described here (https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/asus-vivobook-unity-brightness.html) but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the sound problem thanks to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832248/sound-is-not-working-in-dell-xps-all-in-one-2710-running-ubuntu-16-04). Thanks a lot for this post!
Could anybody help me with issues number 2 and 3 now please?